# python: importing module in package namespace

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

I wonder if there is some standard way to do something like

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import interpolate as sp.interpolate
```

that is not allowed.

Specifically:

1. I'd like to know if there is some reason why the above is not allowed. If I'm  developing my own package foo, it seems reasonable to pollute its namespace as little as possible.
2. Things like

   ```
   import scipy as sp
   __import__('scipy.interpolate')
   ```

   do the job, but are not all that nice and the docs recommend not to use `__import__`, unless strictly necessarily. Similarly

   ```
   import importlib
   import scipy as sp
   importlib.import_module('scipy.interpolate',sp)
   ```

does the job, but it is still ugly, even longer and puts importlib in the namespace...

Comment: I don't think it pollutes the namespace to use `import scipy as sp` see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Comment: It is not the `import scipy as sp`, rather the many import scipy.xxx that are subsequently used to import the integrate, interpolate, signal, ... submodules of scipy.  I would like to have them all under `sp`

Answer (score 0):

Imported modules are treated like regular objects so if you really want to you can import a module and assign it to an arbitrary variable like so

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import interpolate 
sp.interpolate = interpolate
```

sp.interpolate will behave as expected, it just points to the interpolate module whenever you call sp.interpolate. They are the same object underneath, i.e

```
print sp.interpolate is interpolate
>>> True
```

Then to finally remove the original 'interpolate' pointer call

```
del interpolate
```

Comment: and then `del interpolate` I suppose.  The reason I would like to do this is really to prevent IDEs from confusing users. If I make my module foo, when people work with foo in common python IDEs, typing `foo.` starts the autocompletion with anything that in there. And I do not like all the scipy modules that I'm using to show up. Particularly, I don't like inexpert users to wonder if the `interpolate` they see as `foo.interpolate` is actually part of foo or not.  Most IDEs seem not to look at `__all__` and autoexpand only the official package interface.

Comment: Yes, if you want to get rid of the interpolate pointer completely then use `del interpolate` and the interpolate module will only be available through the `sp.interpolate` pointer that you defined.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the deletion of the original interpolate pointer. If this answers your question please mark it as correct.